How to correctly set orderHint to preserve checklist item order in Microsoft Planner via Power Automate?
Title:
How to correctly set orderHint to preserve checklist item order in Microsoft Planner via Power Automate?

Question:
I'm working on a Power Automate flow that clones a Microsoft Planner bucket, including tasks and their checklists. While the tasks and checklist items are copied successfully, I'm having trouble preserving the order of the checklist items.
What I'm trying to achieve:

Maintain the order of checklist items based on a number extracted from their titles (e.g., "02 - Point" should come before "03 - Point").
Ensure that the order is consistent after copying tasks and checklists in Planner.
Override the automatically generated orderHint values in Planner to set my desired order.

What I've tried:

Setting orderHint values explicitly:

I attempted to enforce the order of checklist items by setting unique and correct orderHint values when creating them.
Despite providing these values, Planner seems to ignore or overwrite them, generating its own unexpected orderHint values.
This results in the checklist items not being in the desired order.


Updating the checklist in two steps:

Step 1: Send the checklist without worrying about the order, allowing Planner to create the checklist items.
Step 2: Retrieve the task details, sort the checklist items based on the extracted number from their titles, generate new orderHint values, and update the checklist again.
However, this approach didn't work as Planner still seems to overwrite or ignore the orderHint values upon updating.


Re-executing the same action block:

I noticed that when I assign IDs to checklist items, Planner seems to keep them.
I tried re-running the action block that creates the checklist, hoping that using the same IDs and orderHint values would update the existing checklist items and correct the order.
Unfortunately, this didn't work either.



Example Data:
First Task Details Update Input:
{
  "id": "XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe",
  "body/checklist": [
    {
      "id": "13XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe",
      "title": "13 - Complete WAM Report",
      "isChecked": "False",
      "orderHint": "138584735588>M !"
    },
    {
      "id": "12XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe",
      "title": "12 - Send training materials",
      "isChecked": "False",
      "orderHint": "128584735588Hd !"
    },
    // ... additional checklist items ...
    {
      "id": "01XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe",
      "title": "01 - Verify server resources",
      "isChecked": "False",
      "orderHint": "01[E !"
    }
  ]
}

First Task Details Update Output:
{
  "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#planner/tasks('XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe')/details/$entity",
  "@odata.etag": "W/\"JzEtVGFza0RldGFpbHMgQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAQEBAUCc=\"",
  "id": "XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe",
  "description": "...",
  "checklist": [
    {
      "id": "12XOHSedKRd0C2__uUiMabnpYAHPbe",
      "value": {
        "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.plannerChecklistItem",
        "isChecked": false,
        "title": "12 - Send training materials",
        "orderHint": "WT",
        // ... other fields ...
      }
    },
    // ... additional checklist items ...
  ]
}

As you can see, the orderHint values in the output are different from what I provided. Planner seems to have generated its own orderHint values.
Second Task Details Update Input (Same as First):
I attempted to run the same update again with the same input, hoping it would correct the order, but the orderHint values were changed again by Planner.
Attempts to Sort Checklist Items:
I also tried sorting the checklist items using a Python script based on the orderHint values, but since Planner overwrites them, this hasn't helped.
Question:

How can I correctly set the orderHint values for checklist items in Microsoft Planner via Power Automate to preserve the desired order?
Is there a specific format or method required to ensure that Planner accepts and respects the orderHint values I provide?
Are there best practices for generating orderHint values that Planner will not overwrite?

Additional Information:

I extract the number from the title using the expression: first(split(items('Apply_to_each')?['title'], ' - ')).
Based on this number, I sort the checklist items and assign new orderHint values.
Planner seems to generate its own orderHint values regardless of what I send, which disrupts the intended order.

Any guidance or examples on how to properly set orderHint values so that Planner accepts them would be greatly appreciated.
Note: We are not authorized to use the graph API, so we need to find a solution via power automate
